# why regex cannot find string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The string is: **Byredo Perfume Oil Roll-On Blanche 7.5ML** 
I want to get *7.5* from the string.

```
$productinfo['title'] = 'Estee Lauder Sensuous Noir EDP 50ML';
if (preg_match('/.*\s(\d+)\s?ml/', strtolower($productinfo['title'])))
{
preg_match('/.*\s(\d+)\s?ml/', strtolower($productinfo['title']), $C);
$mlsize = $C[1];
echo $mlsize;
    }
```

This code works great. And I get **50** from this code. But when the **$productinfo['title']** equals to this: *Byredo Perfume Oil Roll-On Blanche 7.5ML* the code is not working. I want to get *7.5* from the string

Comment: `ml !== ML` Use the `/i` switch for `case-insensitive`

Comment: You also need to search for `.`, i.e. `[\d.]+`

Comment: can anyone put here some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*\s(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\s?ml
```

Try this.See demo.The reason your regex is not working is you are capturing integers but there is `.` ie it is a float.To capture float use this regex.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/45

```
$re = "".*\\s(\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s?ml"i";
$str = "Byredo Perfume Oil Roll-On Blanche 7.5ML ";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: @AyxanƏmiraslanlı you have missed some `"` .Either use delimiters or the exact code for php given